# How do I grab the custom parameter from a google adsense ad as the user arrives to the page?

Tags: php, adsense

Been poking around, trying to figure out how to dynamically switch content based on where the user comes from. I've learned that I can do this with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` and such, but I think the cleanest way to do it is to just set custom adsense parameters and grab them. I just, uh... Don't know how. Other answers suggest doing this but don't provide any syntax, and I'm not clear on whether to grab it from the previous url, or current URL. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) is a good way, but it can be changed or not even be set

Comment: Can you please share some code of your attempts? That would be very helpful to us and it might help us to answer your question.

Comment: @StefanN - If I were to start typing without knowing, the first thing I'd try is '$_GET("adsenseParam")', assuming that the ad would send it in the URL. Then some if statements deciding what to render based on what it catches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just a simple $_GET() request. Google allows for adding URL parameters to ad links. My co worker set them up the (vague) way I requested, and it was simple to switch out the landing banners based on which ad the user clicked from.